# How to wait until a asynchronous function finish running then only run continue another function in swift?

Tags: ios, function, asynchronous, synchronization, dispatch

My problem is that , I have a function that i would like it to finish running all code before continue to another function . While running i hope that i can do other stuff like change view . I run my current fucntion and it is Asynchronous and it direct go to another function without running finish all the code if i run synchronous i can't change my view and all code wait for it i cant do anything at all .So i hope that someone can provide an answer to this. Asynchronous seems to skip and directly run another function which require the previous function .

Comment: Can you please post some related code?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

From what you have shared i understand that you are calling an Asynchronous function and you need to do something only after the execution of the Asynchronous function. For this purpose you can use completion handlers.

You can get more information from the following links

[Link 1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)

[Link 2](http://fuckingswiftblocksyntax.com/)

[Link 3](https://grokswift.com/completion-handlers-in-swift/)

Hope this helps you...